# How do I enable the wifi when the hardware switch doesn't work?

Tags: 12.04, wireless

How do I enable the wifi on my laptop lenovo G50-30?

Comment: Is the hardware switch actually broken?  Have you confirmed that the wifi card problem is due to the hardware switch and not drivers being missing?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no hardware switch on this laptop.

Comment: @Pilot6 even virtual via a key combo on the system to toggle wifi on and off? (it's not a physical switch but it's still a 'switch')

Comment: There is no any HW switch on this model. That used to be a problem for the kernel module.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary fix you can run in terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

To make this setting permanent run:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

This issue has been fixed in recent Ubuntu kernels. I suppose in 3.13 for `precise` too. But it needs to be checked.

I was the author of the patch fixing the issue.